# How to add and remove a current state to a link when another is clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

**Hi there**, it my first time here - please go easy on me!

I am struggling to find an answer to my question which is:

How to add and remove a CSS *.current* class to a link when another link is clicked. For example, using this code:

`<a class="boldthislink">Bold me?</a>

<a class="boldhim">bold him</a>

<a class="unboldhim">unbold him</a>`

I want to make the first link bold by clicking the 2nd link and then unbold by clicking the third link. **Is this possible?**

For another example,

My dev site is here: [Karls dev site](http://www.kargo2.com/Stackover/)

On my dev site I want to make the `<a>` link 'background' underline/bold when you click '**Next**' underneath the first paragraph of text, which will also send you to the next spread as it currently does. Then on the next page, when you click '**Previous or next**' the link 'background' isn't underlined anymore, only the nav link of the spread that you are on, and so on.

Any help would be very appreciated!! Im a beginner with Jquery, and most of my code is open source taken from various places so may look scrappy to you! :-)

Many thanks, Karl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bare minimum code** (not optimized, polished, loved, given an education, or otherwise treated kindly):

```
$('a.boldhim').click(function ()
{
    $('a.boldthislink').addClass('current');
});

$('a.unboldhim').click(function ()
{
    $('a.boldthislink').removeClass('current');
});
```

Make sure you're calling it inside of a document ready handler, e.g. one of these:

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* your code here */ });
```

or this (which shorthand for the above):

```
$(function () { /* your code here */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

These basic things are pretty much covered in every jquery tutorial. Try reading this one:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Pay attention to selectors and events.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boldhim').click(function() {
    $('.boldthislink').css('font-weight', 'bold');
  });
  $('.unboldhim').click(function() {
    $('.boldthislink').css('font-weight', 'normal');
  });
});
```

Or in your case you can do it like that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next').click(function() {
    $(a.current).removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
  });
  $('.prev').click(function() {
    $(a.current).removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi infinity, this also helped me on my learning curb. Thanks for the response, all the answers on here have been great and im well on my way to achieving what I need. Very impressed with all the answers on this site. First time ive used it, and i'll def try to contribute something back.

Answer (score 0):

Make them all the same class, using linkclass in this example.

```
$('.linkclass').click(function(){
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

This has the advantage of being scalable - you can have as many or as few links as you like and only one will be 'current' at any given time.